# How can I update text of TextView in thread using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm receiving UDP data from server and I want to show the UDP data to a `TextView`.
But NullPointerException occurs everytime. I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
open class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var readSocket: DatagramSocket
        lateinit var readPacket: DatagramPacket
        val buffer = ByteArray(2048)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        println("Create Runnable example!")
        val threadWithRunnable = Thread(UdpDataArrival())
        threadWithRunnable.start()

        // Add text to textView1
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)
        textView.setText("Hello World from main!\n")

        println("MainActivity onCreate success.")
    }

}
```

This class is thread to keep receiving UDP data

```
class UdpDataArrival: Runnable, MainActivity() {

   override fun run() {
       println("${Thread.currentThread()} Runnable Thread Started.")
       readSocket = DatagramSocket(Settings.remotePort)
       readSocket.broadcast = true
       readPacket = DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.size)
       while (true) {
           receiveUDP()
       }
   }

   open fun receiveUDP() {
       try {
            // Keep a socket open to listen to all the UDP traffic that is destined for this port
            readSocket.receive(readPacket)
            println("open fun receiveUDP packet received = " + readPacket.data)

            str = String(readPacket.data, 0, readPacket.length, Charsets.UTF_8)

            println(str)

            // I tried to update textview in here but the exception occurs
            //textView1.setText(str)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
           println("open fun receiveUDP catch exception.$e")
           e.printStackTrace()
        }
//        finally {
//           readSocket?.close()
//        }

    }
}
```

What should I do to show the 'str' to the TextView?

This is the stacktrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:173)
> at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
> at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:744)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:839)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223)
> at com.example.socketclientkotlin.UdpDataArrival._$_findCachedViewById(Unknown Source:25)
> at com.example.socketclientkotlin.UdpDataArrival$receiveUDP$1.run(MainActivity.kt:78)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Comment: please post your stack trace

Comment: @a_local_nobody post it

Comment: did u try making a lateinit var on top level?

Comment: try just moving your `val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)` above the thread code

Comment: @a_local_nobody Sorry but I really don't know how to change it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add UI thread surround settext or access any UI Widget inside UI thread

```
runOnUiThread {
   textView.setText(str)       
}
```

Comment: i put that code in fun receiveUDP but still occur error

Answer (score 0):

```
runOnUiThread {
   textView.setText("Type your text here")       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it to make 'UdpDataArrival' class to inner class of MainActivity
and used below code and it works!!:

```
runOnUiThread {
    textview.setText(str)
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you solve the problem by clicking on the tick-mark, rather than posting your own answer.